# How to import dashboard stickies from an old hard disk without using migration assistant?

Tags: macos, dashboard-widget

I recently installed a new hard drive in my Macbook Pro for a fresh installation of OSX Lion.

How can I get my dashboard stickies from the old hard disk without using migration assistant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to copy two files from the old installation of OSX:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboard.plist
~/Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.stickies.plist
```

The first tells Dashboard which Widgets to show, the second contains your notes.

Copy these to your new `~/Library/Preferences` and you should be good.

You'll need to restart, logout and login, or kill the Dock, for example by opening Terminal and running `killall Dock`.

It worked for me - but I should warn that my home path was the same on the old install and new install.

Comment: While we're on the subject, have you found a way to get stickies to retain type and size information? There is a "use as default" menu item but it has no effect (for me anyway).

Comment: I don't know if I've ever been able to resize the stickies on the dashboard, sorry I'm of no help.

Comment: Chris: resizing is not the problem (it's easy), remembering a default typeface and size is my question. I find the default 10 pt Helvetica (or whatever it is) tough to read and prefer a larger typeface. I'd like all new stickies to assume that size and typeface. I thought if I just changed one to what I wanted, then chose "use as default" it would work. It has never worked for me. I'm wondering if you or anyone else has ever had this work. I should probably post this as a new question...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you guys are in the users library (Users/Your username/Library) which I believe is hidden by default. This is different than the computer's Library folder (contains application support and all the other non-user dependent stuff).

I was able to find the file there when I originally thought it would be in the main library folder.